# Adapt class containing a string member as synthesized attribute

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-fusion

I’m trying to parse a character string into an attribute of a custom type `symbol`, which contains a `std::string` member. I thought I could use `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` here but that doesn’t work.

If I declare the rule as `rule<It, std::string(), space_type>` it works. If I define it as `rule<It, symbol(), space_type>` it fails with the error “no type name `value_type` in `symbol`”. I think Spirit is trying to append the value character-for-character to the attribute, which fails as expected. But isn’t there a way of making this work, **without** adding an additional intermediate rule which captures the `std::string` attribute?

Here’s the full MWE:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>

struct symbol 
{ 
    std::string repr; 
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(symbol, (std::string, repr))

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
struct test_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, symbol(), qi::ascii::space_type> {
    test_grammar() : test_grammar::base_type{start} {
        start = qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")];
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, symbol(), qi::ascii::space_type> start;
};

#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    test_grammar<std::string::iterator> grammar{};
    auto input = std::string{"test"};
    auto output = symbol{};
    auto e = end(input);
    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin(input), e, grammar, qi::ascii::space, output))
        std::cout << output.repr;
}
```

Comment: This is a known limitation/bug in Spirit. I believe it happens when you adapt structs that have a single element and that element is a "container". The usual workaround is `start %= eps >> lexeme[+char_('a', 'z')];`, apparently this forces the attribute of the right hand side to be `tuple<std::string>` and that works fine with your adapted struct. I'll try to find a duplicate.

Comment: @cv_and_he Yep it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0634b0eb16d67e46) with that workaround

Comment: @cv_and_he Please copy this into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @sehe Your “fix” is dodgy. Why did you remove the `string` include?! Why reorder the headers? (In fact, now that i look at it, why *any* of those changes?)

Comment: rollback if you're not interested. In which I'll also refrain from spending more time on answering...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen from the linked dupe, you can get around this with a well-placed `qi::eps`.

```
    start = qi::eps >> qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("a-z")];
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83334f0ba8ead0fa)**

However, there are cases where `qi::eps` doesn't save. (Will try to find links later). Therefore, I've come to favour the 'old-fashioned approach' for attribute compatibility:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct symbol 
{ 
    std::string repr; 

    symbol(std::string repr = std::string()) : repr(std::move(repr)) {}
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
struct test_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, symbol(), qi::ascii::space_type> {
    test_grammar() : test_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start = as_string[ lexeme[ +char_("a-z") ] ];
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, symbol(), qi::ascii::space_type> start;
};

#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    test_grammar<std::string::iterator> grammar{};
    auto input = std::string{"test"};
    auto output = symbol{};
    auto e = end(input);
    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin(input), e, grammar, qi::ascii::space, output))
        std::cout << output.repr;
}
```

This is also likely a bit lighter on the compiler. See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1257ada5c605a3d7)** as well.

If all else fails you can have your cake and eat it too because attribute transformation/assignment are *customization points* in the library.

- [Attribute Propagation and Attribute Compatibility](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/attribute-propagation-and-attribute-compatibility/)
- [Store a Parsed Attribute Value (Qi)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/assign_to.html)
- [Store Parsed Attribute Values into a Container (Qi)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/store_value.html)
- search for these traits in answers on SO for good examples